# CSS get width auto value to set margin in other class

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, width, sidebar, overlap

I haven't been able to find a similar question about this. However, I am using Bootstrap 4 (accordingly with Admin LTE 3) and I want to make my main-sidebar the correct size to fully display each link in my menu list. It appears that main-sidebar's width is set staticaly in AdminLTE.css to 250px.
Due to languages translation issue, some texts are longer than 250px and I don't want a scrollbar to display.

Is this possible to adapt main-sidebar's width to text content ?
I tried to find my way in putting `width: auto` for my `.main-sidebar`, but the thing is the other part of the page goes behind my main-sidebar which is not what I want to because of `margin-left`:

```
.main-sidebar {
    width: 250px;
}

body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .content-wrapper, body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .main-footer, body:not(.sidebar-mini-md) .main-header {
    transition: margin-left .3s ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 250px; 
}
```

width and margin-left have to be the same here, is there a way to make it dynamic using only CSS ?

Thanks for your help